# Проверка cтроки на float

Tags: python

Задание написать игру.
Программа принимает только целые числа, если пользователь вводит число с плавающей запятой (float) или вводит буквы(str) выдать ошибку и закончить игру.

```
if num_user.isalpha():
    print('Ошибка! нельзя вводить буквы...')
elif not num_user.isdigit():
    print('Ошибка! нельзя вводить дробные числа...')
else:
    num_user = int(num_user)
    if num_user == num_pc:
        print("Вы угадали!")
```

Подскажите как сделать проверку строки на float? использовать только if, else, elif и методы строки

Comment: Завернуть `num_user = float(num_user)` в try-except и не городить костыли

Comment: @andreymal Это было бы лучше всего, но в задании запрещено использовать try-except, циклы, только if else elif

Comment: Странное задание. Надо делать такие задания, чтобы учили тому, что используется в реальности.

Comment: @Глеб Это одна большая задача в нескольких вариациях, в одной разрешено использовать все возможности языка, в другой появляются ограничения

Comment: Ну так используй регулярки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть метод `isdigit`, проверяет строку на то что она состоит только из цифр.

```py
if not num_user.isdigit():
    print("Ошибка!")
else:
    num_user = int(num_user)
    if num_user == num_pc:
        print("Вы угадали!")
```

А чтобы проверить все целые числа, и отрицательные в том числе, можно использовать регулярное выражение:

```py
import re

def is_integer(s):
    return bool(re.match(r'^-?\d+$', s))

# ...

if not is_integer(num_user):
    print("Ошибка!")
else:
    num_user = int(num_user)
    if num_user == num_pc:
        print("Вы угадали!")
```

Если же в задании нельзя ирегулярные выражения использовать нельзя то можно сделать следующую проверку

```py
def is_integer(s):

    # Проверяем, что строка не пуста
    if not s:
        return False
    
    # Убираем пробелы с начала и конца строки
    s = s.strip()
    
    # Проверяем, что строка начинается с '-' для отрицательных чисел
    if s[0] == '-':
        # Если строка состоит только из символа '-', возвращаем False
        if len(s) == 1:
            return False
        # Убираем '-', и далее проверяем что все остальные символы являются цифрами
        s = s.replace('-', '', 1)
        # Либо же сокращенно
        # s = s[1:]

    return s.isdigit()

# ...

if not is_number(num_user):
    print("Ошибка!")
else:
    num_user = int(num_user)
    if num_user == num_pc:
        print("Вы угадали!")
    if num_user < 0:
        print("Вы ввели отрицательное число")

# ...
```

Comment: Вот...то что нужно! Спасибо

Comment: @BaLamuT а что насчёт отрицательных чисел, в которых знак минуса не является цифрой?

Comment: @andreymal хм..а тут вы правы ибо дальше есть проверка на отрицательные числа

Comment: @BaLamuT Я обновил ответ, добавил другой способ проверки строки на то что число является целым, не важно положительным или отрицательным

Comment: @BaLamuT Если ответ мой вариант решения подходит то вы можете поставить галочку "Ответ"

Comment: @E1mir спасибо но isdigit подходит так как использовать только if else elif и методы, осталось отдельно додумать проверку на то если число меньше 1 или -1

Comment: То есть регулярные выражения использовать нельзя?

Comment: @E1mir в том и дело что нет, в задании сказано только if, else, elif методы cтроки, весь код выглядит следующим образом (правка)

Comment: @BaLamuT обновил ответ, использую теперь только стандартные проверки

Answer (score 0):

Проверкой на float в случае ввода может служить наличие `.` или `,`

Тогда проверка будет такой:

```
if ("." in line) or (',' in line):
    pass
```

А вообще будет разумно использование regex выражение на проверку соответствия символов в строке необходимым.

Comment: Число `1e5` с вами не согласно

Comment: @andreymal Да, пожалуй, но если есть проверка на символы, то наверное подойдёт.

Answer (score 0):

Для проверки, представлено-ли число в соответствующем формате, есть специальная функция:

```
if isinstance(num_user, float):
    print ('Ошибка. Числа с плавающей точкой запрещены')
```

Вторым оператором isinstance() есть класс (тип) на принадлежность которого выполняется проверка.

Встроить ее в свой код, надеюсь, сумеете самостоятельно.

P.S. Как мне тут подсказал уважаемый  **andreymal** и необходимо учесть, что данные еще не преобразованы к числовому формату, а находятся в формате *str*, то тогда еще все проще:

```
num_user = '5'
print(num_user.isnumeric())

num_user = '-5'
print(num_user.isnumeric())

num_user = '0.5'
print(num_user.isnumeric())

num_user = '1e5'
print(num_user.isnumeric())
```

Результат:

```
True
False
False
False
```

Т.е. достаточно просто написать:

```
if not num_user.isnumeric():
    print ('Ошибка формати ввода')
else:.....
```

*isnumeric* -  это и есть метод строки, как оно и требуется по условию.

Comment: В пользовательском вводе `num_user` будет строкой

Comment: @andreymal - Спасибо, дополнил ответ.